# I'm trying to connect to a remote Omnis Data file with ODBC using PHP

Tags: php, networking, odbc

We're wanting to create some html reports for clients for easy viewing of data within their Omnis database so that they don't have to do a full log into Omnis to get some basic information. We've been working with php and odbc and things are working without any issues on our testing environment, which is all on the same computer.

We then moved to testing it more, this time by placing the datafile onto a server, and linking the odbc driver to that datafile. It dies with:

```
Warning: odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]: SQL error: Unable to read disk (bad disk), SQL state 08001 in SQLConnect in C:\xampp\htdocs\jP\includes\database.php on line 22
```

The ODBC link works fine with Excel we can look at and read all the records as needed.
The datafile on the server is a direct copy of the datafile on the local computer, same user name and passwords.

Line 22 in the php file is

```
$odbc_conn =  odbc_connect($name_odbc, $odbc_user, $odbc_pass)
```

The user name and password are correct, we've also tried leaving them blank, which works on the local data, but neither work with the remote data.

The server is sitting on the same network, and we have tried two different servers, with the same result for both.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the perms on the datafile sufficient that the process running the PHP interpreter has access to it? Also, here is what microsoft has to say about that exact sql state: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195566

Comment: @Zarathuztra, do you know where I would go to change the perms for this? It still confuses me that MS Excel has no issue accessing the same datafile using the same ODBC System DSM

Comment: Microsoft (Windows) has its own permission system that I'm not 100% familiar with (I'm a strict Unix guy) but I do believe if you view the file properties under the security settings you can find them. As far as programmatically checking them, I'm SOL when it comes to that. Sorry :/

Answer (score 2):

Randall casts "Resurrect" on thread:

I had this exact same problem: attempting to open an OMNIS datafile over a network connection. The solution that worked for me was to set the filename in the 32-bit ODBC DSN connection manager as the network path to the file (\SERVER\Directory\File.cf1) rather than via the drive map. Using the drive map caused this error.